# Updating jquery 1.4.2 to 1.5.2

Tags: jquery

When I started my site, 1.4.2 was the latest version of jQuery.  I link to it directly to google using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in my headers. I figure I need to update to the latest version if anything for the bug fixes.  I know I can just change the version number to `1.5.2` in my url up there but is there any reason I wouldn't want to?  I've never updated so I don't know if there would be any issues with my current code.

I'm going to run a few tests and try it to see if anything breaks but I wanted to ask here and see if anyone had any first hand experiences doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 1.4.2 to 1.5.2 you shouldn't have any problems. Nothing seems to be removed:
http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/

Comment: I want a feature of 1.5 in 1.4.2, namely the `ajaxTransport`. How do I get that?

Comment: By upgrading ;) otherwise, I don't think there's any easy way

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the data type of some of my ajax calls from 'json' to 'text json'.  That was the main thing.  I would definitely spend some time testing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would recommend that you test this migration on a test site before you go live. Sounds like you want to just update a live site.

If you don't have ability to test it, I would recommend that you make the changes during a low usage time and then test the site. If anything goes wrong, you can just roll it back by changing the script to point back to the old version.